# Draw various plots in one figure

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

The image below shows, what i want, 3 different plots in one execution but using a function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbOLY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2pIg.png)

I used the following code:

```
def box_hist_plot(data):
    sns.set()
    ax, fig = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(20,5))
    sns.boxplot(x=data, linewidth=2.5, ax=fig[0])
    plt.hist(x=data, bins=50, density=True, ax = fig[1])
    sns.violinplot(x = data, ax=fig[2])
```

and i got this error:
inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

Comment: Try this instead: fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(20,5))

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you should not call a Figure object `ax` and an array of Axes object `fig`, your problem comes from the line `plt.hist(...,ax=...)`. `plt.hist()` should not take an `ax=` parameter, but is meant [to act on the "current" axes](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html?highlight=current%20axes). If you want to specify which Axes you want to plot, you should use `Axes.hist()`.

```
def box_hist_plot(data):
    sns.set()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(20,5))
    sns.boxplot(x=data, linewidth=2.5, ax=axs[0])
    axs[1].hist(x=data, bins=50, density=True)
    sns.violinplot(x = data, ax=axs[2])
```